# How to add a global URL prefix for all APIs deployed under one WSO2 micro integrator instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

Is it possible to add a global URL prefix for all APIs deployed under one WSO2 micro integrator instance? (without using the API Manager) for example:

Current URLs: https://localhost:8443/houses, https://localhost:8443/shops

Add a configuration to define a prefix "/api" for all APIs so to call the houses API we will have to use: https://localhost:8443/api/houses and to call the shops API: https://localhost:8443/api/shops

I am using the latest Micro integrator version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible OOB. The best option is to deploy a reverse proxy like Nginx proxying Micro Integrator and have the custom context mapping there.